# Vuejs Axios JSON data can't pass to Controller in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I made contact form. It works fine. so my next step that I'm trying to recive data by vuejs + axios.

**I use this gentleman's awesome code.**

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-vue-js-axios-post-request-example-and-demoexample.html

so I could pass the data as json. However I couldn't pass the json data to mysql.

I'm not sure about "response" part and Controller writing.
Could you teach me what is wrong please?

> Controller

```
public function saveContact(Request $request) { 
$this->validate($request, [
   'name' => 'required'         
]);

//original code is this   $contact = new Contact($request->all());
$contact = new Contact(json($request->all()));

//$contact = new Contact($request->all());        
$contact->save();

  return back()->with('success', 'thnak you');
}
```

> web.php

```
Route::get('contact-us', [ ContactController::class, 'getContact' ]);
Route::post('contact-us', [ ContactController::class, 'saveContact' ])->name('contact-us');
```

> ExampleComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">json data return</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form @submit="saveContact">
                            <strong>name</strong>

                            <input
                                type="text"
                                class="form-control"
                                v-model="name"
                            />
                            {{ name }}

                            <button class="btn btn-success">sent</button>
                        </form>

                        <strong>Output:</strong>
                        <pre>
                        {{ output }}
                        </pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log("Component mounted.");
    },

    data() {
        return {
            name: "",
            description: "",
            output: "",
        };
    },

    methods: {
        saveContact(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            let currentObj = this;

            axios

                .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/saveContact", {
                    name: this.name,
                    description: this.description,
                })

                .then(function (response) {
                    currentObj.output = response.data;
                })

                .catch(function (error) {
                    currentObj.output = error;
                });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

[UPDATE] browser log: After submit
[image]

[UPDATE] contact-us.blade.php

```
<div id="emailsend">
  <emailsend-component></emailsend-component>
</div>
@vite('resources/js/app.js')

<form method="post" action="{{ route('contact-us') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 center-block">
      <div class="pull-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-round center-block">submit</button></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

> App.js

```
import "./bootstrap";
import { createApp } from "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js";

import ExampleComponent from "./ExampleComponent.vue";
const newtest = createApp({});
newtest.component("emailsend-component", ExampleComponent);
newtest.mount("#emailsend");
```

Comment: "I couldn't pass the json data to mysql" - what does that mean? Did you check whether the data is sent properly (check this in your browser's network console)?

Comment: Please share all clarification **in text form**, not hidden in a screenshot

Comment: Dear @Nico Haase Thank you for answering me. sorry
I update and add screenshot. This is my current console. I can see the my name data.

Comment: Dear @Nico Haase Thank you for keep helping me. 
I update my blade and vue file. this is all file.

Comment: I'm very new vuejs and axios. Is there info good enough? If I missing  let me know.

Comment: You still haven't shared what you've tried to resolve the problem. Is the data submitted properly? Does it reach the controller as expected?

Comment: Sorry I took long. I changed post URL and update my post. 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/saveContact
now I looked Network it say. 404 Not Found.

And I also tried. I change POST URL as 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact-us and type text and click sent.
I got 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Dear @Nico Haase 
Thank you for helping me. I think It's too early to make this app for me. 
I will study basic first. So Thank you very much fro all of you help. I think I  will close this ask.

Comment: First of all are you building an spa or monolithic app? In case of spa , are you using separate frontend that communicates via api with your backend?

Comment: Dear @Ali Thank you for comment. I'm not sure what my app called. This App is Laravel. but I would like to integrate vue3  v-model and compute things just one blade page. so Backend is still Laravel and Mysql.